# Adding a interactive gui to my VB.net application

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio

OK. So first, I will try my best to explain so good. My friend has gotten cursed out on this forum for not explaining, so I will explain. :)

Ok so I have my program built and all. But then it hit me! Wouldn't it be better to add a news feature?  One teeny tiny problem? I cant? How would I implement a interactive code into an HTML page.

Like can i connect a button to a URL that will make the program do something. Almost like you can open cydia tweaks with there identifier and url EXAMPLE: http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/cydia  And then i can add urls so i can update the program, without updating the files.

Or even just a featured news thing would be nice. But how would i implement this perfectly. I tryed a webrowser, but the page is too big for it. I am good at html, not much at css, i mostly use Adobe Muse http://www.adobe.com/Muse

Last question. Kinda defies the first thing i said about having my program finished.

Is there a way i can add a plus button and make it add more buttons and more labels and all?

This would help with allowing users to customize more then what the program can handle. By The Way, its a winter board Theme Maker. So I have a bunch of icons with there bundle identifiers and I create the folders with VB.net and all that stuff. But i want users to be able to click a plus button to add MORE text boxes and file browsers.

Any ideas? Maybe DIM 1 as NewFileBrowser? But i need to move all the buttons and i need it to be able to be clicked an infinity amount of times. I can do the coding for all of these buttons, but i jest need to know how to create them <1 Move them and the button so that the button goes further down each time, and more boxes will go further down. Much help apreciated. THANKS:)

EDIT:

> Are you trying to say that you're wondering how to have a web browser control in a vb.net >app, which displays a web page, and when a button is clicked on the page, your app detects >it and does something? – Thraka

That sums up the top part. I am using windows forms, and it is coded in VB.net

Comment: To ask a good question you want to be concise. Break thoughts up into separate paragraphs. Avoid the CAPS while you're just talking. Really, read up on this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and don't get frustrated or take it personal when someone down votes your question. Figure out why, and try again.

Comment: Thanks:) Gonna fix it up like you said. :)

Comment: Are you trying to say that you're wondering how to have a web browser control in a vb.net app, which displays a web page, and when a button is clicked on the page, your app detects it and does something?

Comment: Yea. Is it possible. If so how? I also edited to make look cleaner. :)

Comment: Good job it looks better. Maybe start rewriting the question to make someone able to know exactly what you're talking about without asking a question. If I had to ask a question to have you clarify your intent, you should update your question and make it very clear as to what you want to do. For example: Interactive code in HTML is very generic, that could mean anything.

Comment: Thanks is it ok to quote people? Like can i quote one of your comments in my edit? Because you  made it sound very clear of what I wanted to do. :)

Comment: Sure. Also, are you using windows forms or wpf?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the object you want, like the button, you can hook the event and have it call code in your form.

1. Find the object using the [Browser.Document.GetElementById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.
2. With that object, add an event handler to the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx for information about the event handler used